# navbar not displaying in block form after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I created this simple navbar with a dropdown menu to be mobile responsive. But the hamburger leaves the links in hyperlink form instead of blocks.

HTML and CSS code

[image]

Mobile CSS

[image]

This is how I expected my webpage to look after loading.

[image]

But i got this instead

[image]

Comment: Please provide code instead of images or use codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

For the `li`, make `text-decoration: none;` and `color: black;`. Add some padding and change the `background-color: grey`.

Also, on Stack overflow, please try to provide images *in* your question (not linking). As for the code you provided in an image, use the "code snippet" toll in the question to let us interact with your code. Since you are new, I did all the code for you, but instead of asking for the code, ask for help in the general direction.

Comment: Thank You, but nothing changed sadly, please can you help me out.